# Why does this VBA error handler not work?

Tags: vba

I expect this simple VBA to silently handle all 10 errors, but for some reason, only the first is handled silently:

```
Public Sub HandleError()
    For i = 1 To 10
        On Error GoTo Continue
        ThrowError

Continue:
        Err.Clear
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub ThrowError()
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1000
End Sub
```

Is this the correct behavior for the code above?  Or is this a bug in VBA?

Comment: Proper usage of `On Error GoTo` requires one of two things to properly re-enable it: (1) `Resume`, `Resume Next`, or `Resume <label>` statement; (2) Exiting the `Sub` or `Function` in which the `On Error GoTo` was made.

See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm for more ideas.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Though I hope this is just a toy project to help better understand things, and not the start of some sort of real scheme to use VBA error handling in this way. Because that will end in tears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looping through your error handling label, so the second error is raised ***within the context of the error handler***, even though the `Next i` instruction moves the code execution to a line above the label.  You need to move execution out of the error handling context explicitly by calling `Resume` after you clear the error. This means that your error handler would either need to be outside of the loop...

```
Public Sub HandleError()
    For i = 1 To 10
        On Error GoTo Continue
        ThrowError
    Next i

    Exit Sub
Continue:
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

...or have a second label to `Resume` to:

```
Public Sub HandleError()
    For i = 1 To 10
        On Error GoTo Continue
        ThrowError

Continue:
        Err.Clear
        Resume NextLoop
NextLoop:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Much ***better*** would be to simply test for the specific error on the specific line of code:

```
Public Sub HandleError()
    For i = 1 To 10
        On Error Resume Next
        ThrowError
        If Err.Number = vbObjectError + 1000 Then Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
        Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If it can be done without the need for `On Error Resume Next`, *that* is generally the better way. Only for sake of performance might it be justifiable, and even then either profuse comments on the whys, or better yet have the essential need of it be placed in its own function. It's just way too prone to abusive usage (along with `Goto`).

Comment: @rskar - I'm not sure I can think of a situation where using the error handler would be more performant than not using the error handler. `On Error Resume Next` followed by a test is much clearer as to the intent of the code, and I'd go as far as to say that it is pretty much the idiomatic VBA equivalent to a try\catch block.  Note that IMHO, this is the ***only*** reason to use `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: "...using the error handler would be more performant than not using the error handler..." I think you misunderstood me, I was addressing specifically on choosing between `On Error Resume Next` vs `On Error GoTo <label>` for perhaps reasons of performance. I was not advocating to forgo the use of error handling at all.

Comment: As for the coding pattern you propose, trying to model after Try/Catch with `On Error Resume Next`, I can't say I can get behind that. I mean, I can appreciate the desire to find something that has a Try/Catch look-and-feel to it in VBA, but the sad fact of the matter is that if there was more than just a call to `ThrowError` happening, there's too much potential that `On Error Resume Next` would hide unanticipated errors, and add to the challenges of troubleshooting.

Comment: @rskar - The pattern using `On Error Resume Next` is for calling one function\method, etc. that has the possibility of throwing a specific error. The code above doesn't have the `Else` block or any handling after the test at all (mainly because the OP's question is more or less a contrived example).  As for "hiding unanticipated errors", that's as simple as `ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then` or a `Select Case Err.Number` instead of the `If`. Note that you change back to normal error handling after you test whatever you need to test. The point is to inline the handling of *anticipated* errors.

Comment: Yep, I can see we're at the point of agreeing to disagree. If it's specified that the pattern is only about scrutinizing a single function call, that's somewhat more liveable. Yet that would still come with caveats on unanticipated errors happening in the error handling code - and that such could go unnoticed with `On Error Resume Next` still in effect.